# Copy and rename a folder in PHP

Tags: php, exec, directory

Hi I need to copy a folder in the user registration and will track the new user name in a folder،
I found this code on the server but does not work

```
        //Bulder Blog Folder
    $Default='blog\Default';
    $New='blog\\';
    $Blog=$New.$BlogName;
    exec("xcopy $Default $Blog /e/i", $a, $a1);
```

Comment: Are you sure: a) you have `xcopy` command on your server? b) `exec` is allowed by PHP settings?

Comment: You should probably be more specific when explaining the problem that you're having. Just saying it doesn't work is not good enough. Was there any error messages?

Comment: I do not know, must ask the web hosting support command (mkdir) works،The only way that I have written the same order?

Comment: I do not give any error, no message, do not like it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer

```
//Windows Server
$Default='User\Default';
$New='User\'.$_POST['UserAddress'];
exec("xcopy $Default $New /e/i");

//Linux Server
$Default='User/Default';
$New='User/'.$_POST['UserAddress'];
exec("cp -r $Default $New");
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#104020) for information.

Since copying full folders isn't build in - you should write your own function to do so:

1. Make new directory that'll store copies of the files [function:mkdir]
2. List contents of folder [function:glob]
3. Foreach this list and copy each file using [function:copy]

If you're too lazy to write this yourself - go here for [rcopy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#104020).